# c# Datagrid not updating after form closed

Tags: c#, .net

This is how I refresh my Datagridview.

The sequence is that when I double click an entry in the datagrid view, it will open up a dialog box. Once I submit that form, the box closes and RefreshDataGrid() is called.

The problem now is that when I update the form and it closes, the datagrid refreshes but the old entries are shown. However if I close that form and re-open it, it shows the correct update.

The strangest thing is that when I add a new entry to the datagridview, it shows up as per normal.

```
private void RefreshDataGrid()
{
    var selected = programInput.SelectedValue;
    if (selected != null)
    {
        var result = programsData.Get(selected.ToString());
        if (result != null)
        {
            programIdInput.Text = result.Id;
            LoadList(result.Id);
        }
    }
    if (selected == "-1")
    {
        RecursiveClearInputs(this.Controls);
        programIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    }
    fieldsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

LoadList

```
private void LoadList(string Input)
{
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    var fields = fieldsData.GetAllByTaskId(Input);
    List<FieldsDGViewModel> fdgvm = new List<FieldsDGViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in fields)
    {
        var f = new FieldsDGViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Order = item.Order,
            IsPrint = item.IsPrint
        };
        fdgvm.Add(f);
    }
    fdgvm = fdgvm.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = fdgvm;
    fieldsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    fieldsDataGridView.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    fieldsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

This is the update function.

```
public bool Update(Field Input)
{
    try
    {
        var f = Get(Input.Id);
        f.Name = Input.Name;
        f.IsPrint = Input.IsPrint;
        f.Order = Input.Order;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `.EndEdit()` method before updating, or making sure that you leave the edited field before updating?

Comment: Sorry what is the .EndEdit method?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit?view=netframework-4.7.2

if you don't leave the edited field before starting the update process, it is not marked as a changed field.

Comment: I added it to the beginning of my FormClosed function and it still doesn't change anything

Comment: I see, you are using a dialog box, you are not editing the field itself in the datagridview. What does your `Get()` function do?

Comment: It gets the object using the ID provided. In this case, it got a Field object based on its iD